# how to add custom theme to jQueryUI themeswitcher?

Tags: jquery-ui, themes

Here: http://jqueryui.com/docs/Theming/ThemeSwitcher
I found nice widget to switch on the fly jQueryUI themes on my page.
And also I've created my own custom theme. How to add it in list of themes?

Comment: I found some solution: saved .js file (from http://jqueryui.com/themeroller/themeswitchertool/) and edited it..added my theme properties. and it's showing up.. But I dunno if it's legal or not? If I'm saved and used their javascript file and loaded it from my host.. What do you think?

Comment: I was thinking the same. It's kind of annoying that the theme switcher doesn't have this out of the box

Answer (score 0):

I used the same solution as you...downloaded the js from http://jqueryui.com/themeroller/themeswitchertool/, saved it as jquery.themeswitcher.js and replaced all http jquery-ui urls with google apis https urls.

The only changes were in the `var switcherpane` where each link looks like:

```
<li><a href=
"http://jqueryui.com/themeroller/css/parseTheme.css.php?....">
<img src=
"http://jqueryui.com/themeroller/images/themeGallery/theme_90_ui_dark.png" alt=
"UI Darkness" title="UI Darkness" /> <span class="themeName">UI
darkness</span></a></li>
```

Which I replaced with:

```
<li><a href="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.23/themes/ui-lightness/jquery-ui.css">
<img src="content/images/theme_90_ui_light.png" alt="UI Lightness" title=
"UI Lightness" /><span class="themeName">UI lightness</span></a></li>
```

You can add your custom images as a `<li>` in the `var switcherpane`.

If you search through the file there are a few other html images that are referenced further down.

As far as legality goes, I'm not too sure but I can't see why you would't be able to as jQuery UI is free and open source.